# import error trying to install a package

Tags: python, import, cython

When I try to install a package for python, the setup.py has the following lines:

```
import os, sys, platform
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import subprocess
from numpy import get_include
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler.Options import get_directive_defaults
```

and I tried to run `python setup.py install` in terminal but I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line  9, in <module>
from Cython.Compiler.Options import get_directive_defaults
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_directive_defaults'
```

I would really appreciate if you could let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Based on the information in your question, it looks like some sub-package of `Cython` isn't installed. Perhaps it's something optional and you need to reinstall it with that part included. Another possibility is it's not the right version for whatever package you're trying to install expects. Check its requirements, they should be listed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Cython as cy

def gdd():
    return cy.Compiler.Options.get_directive_defaults()
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup.py file is using some fairly recent feature (Cython 0.25). Update Cython and you should be fine.

If you have doubts about how to update Cython, ask away.